# How to put delay in Android Async Task

Tags: android, android-asynctask

```
public Long doInBackground(StudentInfo... s)
{
  StudentInfo currentStudent = s[0];

  publishProgress("Creating New User");

  SiddDatabaseHelper dbHelper = SiddDatabaseHelper.getInstance(mContext);
  long newStudentID = dbHelper.addUpdateStudentInfo(currentStudent);

  Log.e("TTT", "saved user() newStudentID " + newStudentID);
  publishProgress("Saving New User in Session");

  try
  {
    Thread.sleep(700);
  }
  catch (InterruptedException e)
  {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return newStudentID;
}
```

I am trying to sleep the `Thread` so that I can show some fancy message in the Parent Activity. Seems like still the `doInBackground()` process is finishing immediately without any delay.

Comment: Welcome on SO! There is not question in your post. Define clearly some context, what you are trying to achieve, what errors you have encountered so far, and ask something specific. Otherwise, people will not be able nor want to help you.

Comment: time in android is measured in milliseconds so 700 milliseconds is not even up to a second...so try increasing it to something like 4000 instead of 700

Comment: try `Thread.currentThread().sleep(5000);` for delay of 5 seconds.

Comment: Some more context on what you are trying to do would be helpful. If need to do something synchronously (show message in a parent activity) maybe using an async component (AsyncTask) is not the best strategy. However if you need to publish something on the UI while doing an operation in the background, AsyncTask has a publishProgress(,,,) method which you can use. It is described on the documentation page for [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate%28Progress...%29)

Comment: I want my AsyncTask to be completed in 2 or three steps. After Each step say(one step takes 10 seconds) I would like to invoke publishProgress(message) to post new progress status in the UI. For that I was trying to put sleep in the Thread to achieve the delay.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want:

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);                 
} catch(InterruptedException ex) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
```

Comment: Adding a Thread sleep on an AsynTask is a bad idea as AsyncTasks in Android are run sequentially on one thread:

"When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution."

This means that ALL running AsyncTasks will be delayed by the sleep amount since they have to wait on this AsyncTask to finish.

Comment: sleep will delay the thread that call it. Be sure to call sleep only on doInBackground